# Getting #DIV/0 error in Google Sheets for AVERAGE, SUM, COUNT, etc on column generated by ARRAYFORMULA

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula

I am trying to get the average value of a column (column C "Profit Margin" in the screenshot) in Google Sheets. For some reason, I get a #DIV/0 error when trying to use any sort of range functions like SUM, AVERAGE, COUNT, etc on this column:

[image]

I feel like it is related to the fact that column C was generated using ARRAYFORMULA, but I'm not sure...

Here is a link to a copy of the spreadsheet if you want to look at the data: [BuyBack Example Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eDb9Vrpmgna8c37JiqOccEJqmfygex6AICIWegIFkwY/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: UPDATE: Sorry, the sharing permissions weren't correctly set on the link I shared. The document should be publicly accessible now.

Comment: Please check the answer and if it solves your question [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it so others can benefit as well. If not, let us know.

Answer (score 3):

*(In your example spreadsheet you have no formulas)*

Most likely your formula calculated results are given in `TEXT` format, so AVERAGE -which needs numbers to make calculations- can NOT give any results and you end up with `#DIV/0!`.

A quick and easy fix:
**To change text cells to number cells, select your range *(`C2:C`)* and choose a number format for it by going to the top menu, `Format` --> `Number`**.

Your other alternative is to use the function [VALUE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094220?hl=en-GB) within the Arrayformula so as to get the results formatted as numbers.

***EDIT (following OP's sharing the sheet)***

Your problem lies on rows 1496-1499.

In your `buys` sheet, rows 1496-1499, in column `M` (Price) the value is `0`.
This causes your formula `=ARRAYFORMULA(1- B2:B3796/A2:A3796)` for Profit margin  in `Sheet1`in column `C`to give `#DIV/0!` which in turn gives `#DIV/0!` in column `E` (Average margin).

To solve this *(as mentioned above)*:

1. Change your formula for `Average margin` to `=IFERROR(average(C2:C), "CHECK your buys")`
2. Check your buys

***Extra tip***: As an additional step, **use conditional formatting** in your `buys` sheet, to easily spot the issues.

Comment: Sorry, I copied from the original document because I can't share it since it has private -customer data in it. The data is not formatted as text. It was formatted as number (I also tried converting it to %) Neither worked. The $ fields are also numeric, not text btw.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the formulation:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(1- IFERROR(B2:B3796/A2:A3796,0))
```

Add validation in division!